# Some tables don't have primary key, how can I fix this issue?

Tags: mysql, performance, index-tuning

I have the following message when running myqsltunner.pl in past this was not present. How can I solve this issues?

```
-------- Galera Metrics ------------------------------------------------------
    [--] Galera is enabled.
    [--] GCache is using 0B
    [!!] Following table(s) don't have primary key:
    [!!]    cphulkd.login_track
    [!!]    mailscanner.audit_log
    [!!]    mailscanner.geoip_country
    [!!]    mailscanner.inq
    [!!]    mailscanner.maillog
    [!!]    mailscanner.mtalog
    [!!]    mailscanner.outq
    [!!]    mailscanner.saved_filters
    [!!]    mailscanner.user_filters
    [!!]    roundcube.cache
    [!!]    roundcube.cache_shared
    [!!]    roundcube.dictionary
    [!!]    tabaklae_wp1.wp_social_users
    [!!]    tabaklae_wp1.wp_wangguardreportqueue
    [!!]    uhlhosti_whmc5.cloudflare_log
    [!!]    uhlhosti_whmc5.cloudflare_plans
    [!!]    uhlhosti_whmc5.cloudflare_ulog
    [!!]    uhlhosti_whmc5.mod_invoicedata
    [!!]    uhlhosti_whmc5.tbladdonmodules
    [!!]    uhlhosti_whmc5.tbladminperms
    [!!]    uhlhosti_whmc5.tblaffiliates
    [!!]    uhlhosti_whmc5.tblconfiguration
    [!!]    uhlhosti_whmc5.tblcustomfieldsvalues
    [!!]    uhlhosti_whmc5.tblknowledgebaselinks
    [!!]    uhlhosti_whmc5.tbloauthserver_access_token_scopes
    [!!]    uhlhosti_whmc5.tbloauthserver_authcode_scopes
    [!!]    uhlhosti_whmc5.tbloauthserver_client_scopes
    [!!]    uhlhosti_whmc5.tbloauthserver_user_authz_scopes
    [!!]    uhlhosti_whmc5.tblpaymentgateways
    [!!]    uhlhosti_whmc5.tblproductconfiglinks
    [!!]    uhlhosti_whmc5.tblservergroupsrel
    [!!]    uhl_vault.vault_uhlautomatic_del
    [!!]    uhl_vault.vault_uhlcache
    [!!]    uhl_vault.vault_uhlcategories_folders
    [!!]    uhl_vault.vault_uhlemails
    [!!]    uhl_vault.vault_uhlexport
    [!!]    uhl_vault.vault_uhlitems_edition
    [!!]    uhl_vault.vault_uhlkb_items
    [!!]    uhl_vault.vault_uhllog_items
    [!!]    uhl_vault.vault_uhlmisc
    [!!]    uhl_vault.vault_uhlrestriction_to_roles
    [!!]    uhl_vault.vault_uhlroles_values
    [!!]    wp_highpassion.wp_icl_locale_map
    [!!] Following table(s) are not InnoDB table:
    [!!]    atecbb_wp1.wp_usermeta
    [!!]    atecbb_wp1.wp_users
    [!!]    cphulkd.auths
    [!!]    cphulkd.ip_lists
    [!!]    cphulkd.known_netblocks
    [!!]    cphulkd.login_track
    [!!]    eximstats.defers
    [!!]    eximstats.failures
    [!!]    eximstats.sends
    [!!]    eximstats.smtp
    [!!]    mailscanner.audit_log
    [!!]    mailscanner.blacklist
    [!!]    mailscanner.geoip_country
    [!!]    mailscanner.inq
    [!!]    mailscanner.maillog
    [!!]    mailscanner.mcp_rules
    [!!]    mailscanner.mtalog
    [!!]    mailscanner.outq
    [!!]    mailscanner.sa_rules
    [!!]    mailscanner.saved_filters
    [!!]    mailscanner.user_filters
    [!!]    mailscanner.users
    [!!]    mailscanner.whitelist
    [!!]    tabaklae_wp1.wp_psp_link_builder
    [!!]    tabaklae_wp1.wp_psp_link_redirect
    [!!]    tabaklae_wp1.wp_psp_monitor_404
    [!!]    tabaklae_wp1.wp_psp_post_planner_cron
    [!!]    tabaklae_wp1.wp_psp_serp_reporter
    [!!]    tabaklae_wp1.wp_psp_serp_reporter2rank
    [!!]    tabaklae_wp1.wp_psp_web_directories
    [!!]    uhlhost_wp1.wp_commentmeta
    [!!]    uhlhost_wp1.wp_comments
    [!!]    uhlhost_wp1.wp_links
    [!!]    uhlhost_wp1.wp_options
    [!!]    uhlhost_wp1.wp_postmeta
    [!!]    uhlhost_wp1.wp_posts
    [!!]    uhlhost_wp1.wp_term_relationships
    [!!]    uhlhost_wp1.wp_term_taxonomy
    [!!]    uhlhost_wp1.wp_terms
    [!!]    uhlhost_wp1.wp_usermeta
    [!!]    uhlhost_wp1.wp_users
    [!!]    uhlhost_wp3.wp_commentmeta
    [!!]    uhlhost_wp3.wp_comments
    [!!]    uhlhost_wp3.wp_links
    [!!]    uhlhost_wp3.wp_newsletter_sent
    [!!]    uhlhost_wp3.wp_options
    [!!]    uhlhost_wp3.wp_postmeta
    [!!]    uhlhost_wp3.wp_posts
    [!!]    uhlhost_wp3.wp_term_relationships
    [!!]    uhlhost_wp3.wp_term_taxonomy
    [!!]    uhlhost_wp3.wp_terms
    [!!]    uhlhost_wp3.wp_usermeta
    [!!]    uhlhost_wp3.wp_users
    [!!]    whmxfer.sessions
    [!!]    wp_highpassion.wp_psp_link_builder
    [!!]    wp_highpassion.wp_psp_link_redirect
    [!!]    wp_highpassion.wp_psp_monitor_404
    [!!]    wp_highpassion.wp_psp_post_planner_cron
    [!!]    wp_highpassion.wp_psp_serp_reporter
    [!!]    wp_highpassion.wp_psp_serp_reporter2rank
    [!!]    wp_highpassion.wp_psp_web_directories
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a new feature, part of the *Galera cluster* support. Galera replication is for InnoDB tables (MyISAM replication can be enabled but it is experimetal) and as it uses row-based replication, the tables should have primary keys to work right and fast.

But you cannot just add them if the tables and applications were not designed to have them. You will have to do an analysis of these tables.

- If there is some non-nullable unique key, it may be changed to a primary key directly as they are effectively the same thing.
- if there is some nullable unique key then you need to assess if the nullability is required.
- You can try to identify the natural keys of your tables (a set of columns uniquely identifying each row) and create a composite PK on them.
- If no (reasonable) combination of columns works, you may add a surrogate key - an autoicrement column.

All but the first will require checking and possibly modifying the application to be compatible with the new table structure.

The real question is - is this really an issue? Are you using Galera cluster?
Many of these tables are supposedly not even InnoDB - if they are MyISAM then the Galera replication is possibly not even working anyway.

For the InnoDB ones, it would be good if you could define the primary keys even if you do not use Galera, because InnoDB depends on primary keys internally and it will pick one automatically even if you do not define it, and if there is no suitable unique key, it will create an inefficient and inacessibe surogate key behind your back.

As a side note - mysqltuner and similar scripts tell you a lot of information, but even the "suggestions" are not to be blindly followed and not everything is an issue. Those are just things you should check and think about them. Never change config based on such suggestion unless you understand what you change and why it is wrong.

Comment: can you tell me how to disable Galera cluster, I believe I am not using it and this is something that occurred not long ago.

Comment: @UhlHosting galera cluster would need at least two nodes and special initialization anyway. Maybe there is just a false positive in the check. See output of `show global variables like 'wsrep_on'` and if it is `1`or `ON` then disable it in your config.

Comment: MariaDB [(none)]> show global variables like 'wsrep_on';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| wsrep_on      | OFF   |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: @UhlHosting then I would say it is some false positive and you can ignore the Galera stuff (looking at the [code](https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/blob/master/mysqltuner.pl#L3185), check the `wsrep_provider_options` too, maybe there is something in there). The suggestion to add the PKs to your InnoDB tables stays relevant but is not critical.